# axios won't let me set a Content-Type when uploading a file

Tags: javascript, axios, content-type

I'm doing:

```
          return axios.request({
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": uploadFile.type // This is set to application/flac
            },
            method: "PUT",
            data: formData,
            url: respAudio.signedUploadUrl,
            timeout: 0,
            onUploadProgress: progressEvent => {
              this.uploadProgress =
                (progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100 - 10;
            }
          });
```

And for `formData`:

```
      let formData = new FormData();
      const uploadFile = document.querySelector("#fileUploadInput").files[0];

      formData.append("file", uploadFile);
```

But the Request Headers show:
[image]

How can I get `axios` to respect the `Content-Type` that I set?

Comment: What is your `formData` variable? In particular, is it an instance of `FormData`?

Comment: Updated code to include `formData`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your `formData` is  a `FormData` instance with a file in it, it doesn't surprise me that `axios` sets the `Content-Type` header to the correct value for uploading a form.

There's no need to change the `Content-Type` of the form data being uploaded. The MIME type of the file is **part of** the data in the form. You'd only change it if you were include the **file** data itself in the PUT, not a form containing the file data.

---

In a comment you said:

> My server needs to know the correct MIME type of the file and all the browser is sending is `multipart/form-data`

The browser is correct. You're sending a **form**, not a **file**. If you want to send a file, don't use `FormData`; read the file data into an `ArrayBuffer` and send that. Something along these lines:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const uploadFile = document.querySelector("#fileUploadInput").files[0];
  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = () => {
    resolve(
      axios.request({
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": uploadFile.type // This is set to application/flac
        },
        method: "PUT",
        data: reader.result,
        url: respAudio.signedUploadUrl,
        timeout: 0,
        onUploadProgress: progressEvent => {
          this.uploadProgress =
            (progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100 - 10;
        }
      })
    );
  };
  reader.onerror = () => {
    reject(/*...*/);
  };
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(uploadFile)
});
```

That may need tweaking, but it's the general idea.

Comment: My server needs to know the correct MIME type of the file and all the browser is sending is `multipart/form-data`

Comment: @Shamoon - The browser is correct. You're sending a **form**, not a **file**. If you want to send a **file**, don't use `FormData`. Read the file data into an `ArrayBuffer` and send that.

Comment: Can you please include a snippet on how to accomplish that?

Comment: @Shamoon - Added. :-)

Comment: @Shamoon - I've, er, never done a PUT request to send a file (with axios or otherwise), so...I'd be really interested to know how this works out and whether you need to tweak it. :-)

Comment: I'm `put`ting directly to a Google Cloud Storage presigned bucket, so I hope it's okay with raw file data

Comment: @Shamoon - I'd expect so. That's what PUT Is for. :-)

Comment: @Shamoon - Thanks for letting me know! :-)